# Unable to convert string (containing a number) to int?

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I have a very silly problem .. I have a string containing "`800.0000`" (without the quotes), which I'm trying to convert to the number 800. I'm using this command, but its not working:

`int inputNumber = Int32.Parse(inputString);`

I get the FormatException, with the message "Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
int inputNumber = Int32.Parse(inputString, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

Answer (score 3):

> 800.000

is of type `Double`, not an `Integer`

so,

```
double inputNumber = Double.Parse(inputString);
```

Will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The Exception occurs because your `string` is no `int32`. You have to convert to `double` first.

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble(youString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double myDouble = Convert.ToDouble(string);
```

works similarly with other types too,

```
int myInt = Convert.ToInteger(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing a number that's got decimals, you'll need to use the appropriate target type - `float` or `double`

So that gives you

```
var value = Double.Parse(s);
```

You can take away the decimals like this:

```
var integer = (int)value;
```

But even with the `Double.Parse` you'll need to be careful, since it will expect different input based on the current culture (`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`).

So while

```
Double.Parse("800.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

works as expected

```
Double.Parse("800.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

will produce the value "80000"

EDIT1 - added:

So you'll might want to use

```
Double.Parse("800.00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

to prevent any misinterpretation that can lead to all kinds of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Int32 valueInInt = (int)double.Parse(inputString);